# How Can I Send Data from Raspberry Pi to MIT App Inventor using RFCOMM

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I want to Send a Data from my Raspberry Pi 3B+ to an MIT App that I created. I can send Data from my MIT to Raspberry Pi even to Arduino using rfcomm-server.py that comes from the PyBlueZ. but I cant seem to do the opposite where I should be able to send data from Raspberry Pi to my MIT App.

```
import bluetooth
server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

bluetooth.advertise_service(server_sock, "SampleServer", service_id=uuid,
                        service_classes=[uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                        profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE],
                        # protocols=[bluetooth.OBEX_UUID]
                        )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel", port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from", client_info)

try:
while True:
    data = client_sock.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print("Received", data)
except OSError:
    pass

print("Disconnected.")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("All done.")
```

Comment: I tinker around rfcomm-client but I cant seem to get around it as I read the documentation. Can someone Help me? Thanks

Comment: If you have the connection established between MIT & RPi with data being received then you have the hard bit done. It would maybe help if you could share your code and be clearer about what is working and what is not. Share any error messages etc. I would expect that you need to add a send in to the PyBlueZ example server. Something like:  `client.send(b'hello`)`. There are more examples at: https://blog.kevindoran.co/bluetooth-programming-with-python-3/

Comment: Yes. I have an established connection between my MIT and RPi.

Comment: In your code you have added, there is no `client_sock.send()`. You will need to add one to send data the other way.

Comment: I used my Raspberry Pi as a Server based on the code above, in which I can receive a Message from MIT. so I think I cant use code like `client.send(b'Hello')` because the RPi is the Server not the Client. But to make sure, I did what you advice, but it just make my Code rerun again without spitting out Error. so Im in a Slump.

Comment: I'll try to use the `client_sock.send()` and send you an Update. Just a Question, can a Server send data to client? I thought only the Client can send Data to Server in which Server can process it. Do I need some sort of setups to make my rfcomm-server to do that?

Comment: Yes there is two way communication between the clients and servers. Client and server is defined more by which one advertises and which one initiates connection.

Comment: Already Resolved. Thanks ukBaz. It Works. `client_sock.send()` works for me. Thank a Lot